# How do I get a count of the Shopify products in a collection using the Ruby API

Tags: ruby, shopify

I want to get the count of products in each collection in the shop as part of a Shopify App that I'm building.

I know that for a single collection  `Product.all(params: {collection_id: 29238895}).count` will show me the count in the shopify console, but I'm not certain about how it is implemented.

The API document describes a call that counts all products that belong to a certain collection `GET /admin/products/count.json?collection_id=841564295` but I have been unable to get a ruby expression that runs this.

Is there a more complete document on the Ruby API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know exactly what is going on with the API, may I suggest the simple command: **bundle open shopify_api**

That will load the entire API into your text editor, allowing to quickly determine the answer to your question. The /lib/resources directory is especially rich, but do not forget to check the base class as well. In fact, I think the count option is declared right in the base itself. Nothing beats a few minutes of examining the code.

Comment: I actually spent a long time examining code, in Github and reading partner forums and here.  This should make it much easier.  Also it seems that shopify-api-limits no longer works, I hope you got your beer back.

Comment: The limiting works. For a prime example of how to deal with them the CLI package for the shopify_theme gem has code that works with the limits well. You can copy& paste from there. Or use the common ActiveResource patch that automatically deals with limiting so you don't have to think about them. Beer?

Comment: Beer? https://github.com/christocracy/shopify-api-limits Readme.  That gem fails in Rails 4.2.1, I think the ActiveResource patch is wrong, but I didn't spend much time on it, just trapped the 429.

Comment: I think Shopify took Chris's code and rolled it into the gem ages ago. In fact, they did that without crediting him too. So they took their lumps and credited him... what it is today is just a module in the gem /resources and limits.rb... same idea right